# How to change overflow menu textcolor in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, textcolor

I have a custom theme that is (mostly) working great. The problem I have is that I cannot figure out a way to change the overflow menu's text color. I realize there are probably ways to do it programmatically but I'm really hoping I can find a solution I can put in the xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Light" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="themeName">Theme.Light</item>
        <!--<item name="android:textColor">#ff000000</item>-->

        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/blue</item>

        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/medium_blue</item>

        <!-- colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated,
        which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/dark_blue</item>

        <!-- You can also set colorControlNormal, colorControlActivated
        colorControlHighlight, and colorSwitchThumbNormal. -->

        <item name="android:actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/Theme.Light.PopupMenu</item>

        <item name="android:textColor">@color/light_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/light_text</item>

        <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/MyStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyStyle" parent="android:style/Widget">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_text</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Light.PopupMenu" parent="android:style/Widget.Material.PopupMenu.Overflow">
        <!-- Required for pre-Lollipop. -->
        <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>

        <!-- Required for Lollipop. -->
        <item name="android:overlapAnchor">false</item>

        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/medium_blue</item>

        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@style/Theme.Light.TextAppearance</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/dark_text</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.Light.TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/dark_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/dark_text</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I realize this is rather messy but I left in several ways I've attempted to change the textcolor. Basically instead of using the default black for the Material theme, I want to the change the overflow menu textcolor to white.

My guess is there's just some attribute I'm not changing but obviously I don't know what it is. I've searched Google and here but haven't found a solution to this.

EDIT: Setting the textColor for the entire theme does affect the overflow menu's text color but also affects every other text's color, obviously. I'm looking for a more specific attribute.